# Arcpy to PostgreSQL using psycopg2 with MULTIPOLYGON using WKT

Tags: arcpy, postgresql, well-known-text, psycopg2

I am trying to create a MULTIPOLGYON in PostgreSQL from WKT format using arcpy.da module and psycopg2. I have had success creating point and multi point shapes this way however I cannot seem to get how to format the code for a MULTIPOLGYON.

I have read over the documentation http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_GeomFromText.html but it does not give any examples of inserting a variable holding the WKT geometry.

this is my part of the code I am having trouble with

```
cur = conn.cursor()  #setting up connection cursor
cur.execute('''drop table polygon''')
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE polygon
            (pid serial primary key,
             Name TEXT,
             geom geometry);''')
conn.commit()
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, ["name","SHAPE@"]):
    name =  row[0]
    geome = row[1].WKT
    cur.execute('''insert into polygon(Name, geom)values(%s, ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON'(%s)))''', (name,geome))
    conn.commit()
```

this is the error

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 20, in <module>
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ...values('Minnesota', ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON'('MULTIPOL...
```

I have tried taking out the 'MULTIPOLYGON' but it still has not worked! what else can I do!

Comment: Your error message says that it has a syntax error on line 20 but the code you presented does not have that many lines.  Please always provide error messages that come from running the precise [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) that you present.

Comment: Based on the error it looks like the word Multipolygon is in your wkt string at least twice, it should only be in there once.  Should look similar to: `ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((-71.1031880899493 42.3152774590236,
-71.1031627617667 42.3152960829043,-71.102923838298 42.3149156848307,`...

Comment: Definitely take out the `MULTIPOLYGON` in code, because that is included in the WKT. You're probably adding one too many sets of brackets. `ST_GeomFromText(%s)` is all you need for that portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many brackets. Based on your code and comments,

```
cur.execute('''insert into polygon(Name, geom)values(%s, ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON'(%s)))''', (name,geome))
```

should be

```
cur.execute('''insert into polygon(Name, geom)values(%s, ST_GeomFromText(%s))''', (name,geome))
```

I also recommend looking into GeoAlchemy 2 as a nicer, more generic, and safer way of writing this.

Comment: ahh gotcha, so geome is going to have MULTIPOLYGON(COORDS)